# PHP e-commerce, shopping cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart

i'm looking for a tutorial on how to create an e-commerce site form scratch that covers things like list of products and categories, user account, wish list, administrator area and of course the shopping-cart etc, something like the *opencart*. I have searched in internet quite a few times but i'm not happy enough with what i found. If anyone knows any good written articles that explain with enough details, and images, or even better any good video tutorial on this please let me know.

p.s if possible no OOP

Comment: shopping cart without OOP ? Like Burger without meat.

Comment: It is possible ( I have this on a very old project that works good ), but I DO NOT recommand it. You should do this with OOP because you could learn some good things.

Comment: @EvilP some people even claim that a burger without meat is possible. I suggest writing it in assembly.

Comment: @EvilP Using OOP does not automatically make your code better. OOP is a programming paradigm.

Comment: But try to implement this application without OOP, this would be a pain in the a**... And OOP is defacto standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming for **beginners** level. This [tutorial](http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/) could help you, It also teaches you the admin panel too for your cart. Or you can even use open source stuff like Oscommerce, magento.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 main shops are: Magento (http://www.magentocommerce.com/) and (http://www.prestashop.com/).

The easiest is prestashop, but magento is more versatile.

You can choose one depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an actual shop, but this tutorial is analogous - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch/

With the forum example, users = shop customers, categories are the same thing, and posts are basically items in the shop. You will need to be a little creative on what features you allow, but the tutorial goes over building all the basic components. For the check out process, the PayPal documentation is well written and reasonably clear to follow:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf